# check if a file is 'complete' (with python)

Tags: python, macos, file-io

is it possible to check if a file is done copying of if its complete using python?
or even on the command line.
i manipulate files programmatically in a specific folder on mac osx but i need to check if the file is complete before running the code which makes the manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know where the files are being copied from, you can check to see whether the size of the copy has reached the size of the original.

Alternatively, if a file's size doesn't change for a couple of seconds, it is *probably* done being copied, which may be good enough.  (May not work well for slow network connections, however.)

Comment: i dont know where files come from. but the file size change could be an option.

Comment: it seems like the size stays at 0 till the file is complete. its the simplest and fastest way to get what i want.

Comment: That's interesting. It might be platform-specific behavior, or might vary depending on the size of the files, though, so be careful!

Comment: don't think its filesize specific, tried different file sizes and it stays at 0 for all. it might be OSX specific but i need it only on that platform.

Answer (score 4):

There's no notion of "file completeness" in the Unix/Mac OS X filesystem. You could either try locking the file with [`flock`](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock) or, simpler, copy the files to a subdir of the destination directory temporarily, then move them out once they're fully copied (assuming you have control over the program that does the copying). Moving is an atomic operation; you'll know the file is completely copied once it appears at the expected path.

Comment: [A *great* article on file locking in general and in Python](http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=201012#13), if you're interested.

Comment: i have a program that does operations on files based on FSevents so i cant copy or lock it in my case.

Answer (score 3):

take the md5 of the file before you copy and then again whenever you think you are done copying. when they match you are good to go. use md5 from the [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) module for this.

Comment: i don't control the copying. i only fire up functions on fileevents. so i can't take the md5 of a file i don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have control of the (python?) program doing the copying. What commands are you using to copy? I would think writing your code such that it blocks until the copy operation is complete would be sufficient.

Is this program multi-threaded or processed? If so you could add file paths to a queue when they are complete and then have the other thread only act on items in the queue.

Comment: no i dont have control over the copying. i fire up actions based on file events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lsof](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) and parse the opened handle list. If some process still has an opened handle on the file (aka writing) you can find it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import os

# Get the file size two times, now and after 3 seconds.
size_1 = os.path.getsize(file_path)
time.sleep(3)
size_2 = os.path.getsize(file_path)
# compare the sizes.
if size_1 == size_2:
    # Do something.
else:
    # Do something else.
```

You can change the time to whatever suits your need.